# CRC32 code does not work

Tags: verilog, crc32

I just started to work with CRC32.So when I wanted to check the code I wrote and I get xxxxxx as the output.I am not sure if the code is right though

```
module last_time(input [127:0]finalinput,output  [31:0]crcout1
    ,input clk);


wire [31:0]poly;
assign poly=32'h04c11db7;
reg [7:0]lsb;
reg [3:0]i;
reg [7:0]ans;
reg [31:0]nextcrc;
reg [31:0]newcrc;
reg [31:0]crcout;
reg [7:0] lut [255:0];

always@(posedge clk)
begin
 crcout=32'hffffffff;
 lsb=finalinput;

 for(i=0;i<16;i=i+1)
   begin
     ans=(8'hff^(lsb)); 
     newcrc = lut[ans];
     $readmemh("table.txt",lut); // to fill lut
     nextcrc=(newcrc)^(crcout>>8);
     lsb=lsb>>8;
   end
end

assign crcout1=nextcrc^32'hffffffff;  
endmodule
```

Comment: please, spaces are free, use them in the example.

Comment: Okay, thank you for letting me know.

Comment: Why do you sample `lut` before assigning it a value? Why are you loading it 16 times?

Comment: I was trying to run the code initially unsure of my values. I got it running now.The issue was the input to the LUT, it should be an integer value and not a register like I specified in my code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the input to the LUT, it should be an integer and not a reg value.
The LUT size was not the correct size

```
module bit32(input [31:0]msg,input [31:0]crcinitial,output reg[31:0]tableout,output [23:0]crcshifted,
output[31:0]newcrc,output reg [7:0]xor1);
wire [7:0]msglsb;

assign msglsb=msg;
wire [7:0]crclsb;
assign crclsb=crcinitial;
integer k;
reg [31:0]lut[0:255];

initial
begin
 assign xor1=(crclsb^msglsb)&8'hff;
 assign k=xor1;
 assign tableout=lut[xor1];
 $readmemh("table.txt",lut); 
end

assign crcshifted=crcinitial>>8;
assign newcrc=(tableout^crcshifted)^32'hffffffff;
endmodule
```